# Can 32-bit Windows LiveCD modify the Registry of an Offline 64-bit Windows?

Tags: windows, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit, x86, x86-64

Is it possible to mount the NTFS and registry hives from a 64-bit Windows on a 32-bit Windows Preinstallation Environment (32-bit). Does 64-bit change the file format?

Also can x86_64 machines boot unmodified 32-bit OSes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no overall data/schema differences between the registries of 32-bit and 64-bit Windows - obviously the actual content will be different but there's no structural differences no.

And yes an x86 64-bit machine can 100% boot a 32-bit OS straight out of the box.

Comment: content different? by how much? Will strings still be strings?

Comment: yep, that side of things is the same, but things like string contents will be different.

Answer (score 2):

NTFS is the same for 32- and 64-bit, so you will be able to read any files.

As for the structure -

> The registry in 64-bit versions of
>   Windows is divided into 32-bit and
>   64-bit keys. Many of the 32-bit keys
>   have the same names as their 64-bit
>   counterparts, and vice versa. [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305097)

so, your offline editor shall be capable of viewing/changing both parts.